# What is wrong with my TicTacToe code and how do you check already taken spots?

Tags: java, input

I have edited this question. I feel like I am close but for some reason the output of this code prints an extra 'X' or 'O' above the board. I can't pinpoint why it is doing this and also how do I check if a spot is taken and not allow the spot to be overridden. I have tried putting an if(board[i][j]!= ' ') {S.O.P("not valid") }but it does not function correctly. Maybe I'm not writing it in the wrong spot?

The last thing is when I want to restart the game the winner is already declared. How do I get the game to reset the board?

I have been at it for hours and would really appreciate the help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicTacToe
{
public static char[][] board = new char[3][3];

public static char player;
public static void newGame()
{
    System.out.println("New Game: X goes first.");
    player = 'X';
}

public static void writeBoard()
{
    //drawing the game board
    String line = "______";
    System.out.println("");
    //making seperate columns and rows
    for(int i= 0;i<3; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        System.out.print(board[i][j]+"|");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}

public static void getMove()
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i, j;
    if(player == 'X')
    {
        System.out.println("X's Turn");
        System.out.println("Where do you want your X placed?");
        System.out.println("Please enter row number and column number seperated by a space.");
        i = keyboard.nextInt();
        j = keyboard.nextInt();
            if(board[i][j] != ' ')
                System.out.println("That position is taken");
        System.out.println("You have entered row" + " " + i + " "+ "and column" + " " + j);
        System.out.println("Thank you for your selection.");
        System.out.print(board[i][j]='X');
        player = 'O';

    }
    else if(player == 'O')
    {
        System.out.println("O's Turn");
        System.out.println("Where do you want your O placed?");
        System.out.println("Please enter row number and column number seperated by a space.");
        i = keyboard.nextInt();
        j = keyboard.nextInt();
            if(board[i][j] != ' ')
                {
                    System.out.println("That position is taken");
                }
        System.out.println("You have entered row"+" " + i +" "+ "and column" +" " + j);
        System.out.println("Thank you for your selection.");
        System.out.println(board[i][j] = 'O');
        player = 'X';

    }

}


public static boolean winner()
{
    //check the row
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (board[i][0] == board[i][1] && board[i][1] == board[i][2] && (board[i][0] == 'X'))
        {
            System.out.println("X IS THE WINNER");
            return true;
        }
        else if (board[i][0] == board[i][1] && board[i][1] == board[i][2] &&(board[i][0]=='O'))
        {
            System.out.println("O IS THE WINNER");
            return true;
        }

        //check the column
        else if (board[0][i] == board[1][i] && board[1][i] == board[2][i] && (board[0][i] =='X'))
        {
            System.out.println("X IS THE WINNER");
            return true;
        }
        else if (board[0][i] == board[1][i] && board[1][i] == board[2][i] && (board[0][i]=='O'))
        {
            System.out.println("O IS THE WINNER");
            return true;
        }
    }

        //check diagnols from the left
        if (board[0][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][2] && (board[0][0]=='O'))
        {
            System.out.println("O IS THE WINNER!");
            return true;
        }
        else if (board[0][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][2] && (board[0][0] == 'X'))
        {
            System.out.println("X IS THE WINNER!");
            return true;
        }
        //checks diagnols from the right
        else if (board[0][2] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][0] && (board[0][2]=='O'))
        {
            System.out.println("O IS THE WINNER!");
            return true;
        }
        else if (board[0][2] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][0] && (board[0][2]=='X'))
        {
            System.out.println("X IS THE WINNER!");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
}


public static boolean tie()
{
    //If there is no winner(a tie)
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<3;j++)
        {
            if(board[i][j]==' ')
            {
                System.out.println("It's A TIE!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

}







import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicTacToeDemo
{
public static char[][] board = new char[3][3];

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int i, j;
    String answer;

    do{

        TicTacToe.newGame();

        while(!TicTacToe.winner())
        {
            TicTacToe.writeBoard();
            TicTacToe.getMove();
            TicTacToe.tie();
        }

        System.out.println("Would you like a rematch?");
        System.out.println("Enter yes or no");
        answer = keyboard.next();

      } while(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
    //do-while loop to keep game going if wanted to
}
}
```

Comment: I 'am also missing a return statement and have no idea what that is about

Comment: In your method winner(), your loop is useless, because you're returning a value ( and so, exiting the method )  during the first loop.

Comment: I added some brackets and it seemed to go away, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**TicTacToe class**

newGame() is missing return statement, add void

player is not initialized, make it global variable with:

```
private static char player;
public static void newGame()
{
  System.out.println("New Game: X goes first.");
  player = 'X';
}
```

Do some refactoring of winner method, it is too complex. Maybe separate conditions into separate methods for easier readability. You can find lots of examples on how it should be done.

Fix error handling (I entered "22 33" and got ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, also "a b" and I got InputMismatchException), you need to prevent this.

**TicTacToeDemo class**

board is never used, i and j also.

Why do/while? It can be done with just while loop...

This few fixes made it running but you need to address all other issues.

What IDE are you using for development? It should report this errors and give you explanation of it.

Answer (score 1):

When you're making the first move, the player variable is undefined, because it's a local variable for both getMove() and newGame(). Make it global.
Also, you're checking if there is a winner, but not checking which one. You need to check, if it's line of 'X's, or 'O's, and return the winning player, as a char, for example, and some other char, if there is no winners.

So, it should be like this:

```
char player;
public static void newGame()
{
    System.out.println("New Game: X goes first.");
    player = 'X';
}
```

Also, in method getMove():

```
public static void getMove()
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    char player; <- Delete this line!!!!
    int i, j;
    if(player == 'X')
```

Comment: I have tried to make it global and it still shows the error! Thank you for the feedback. I fixed the winner method

Comment: So, make sure, what you're first calling newGame(). And, the most important thing, show the main method, it can help to find the issue

Comment: I added the other class for reference.

Comment: Have you changed TicTacToe class? Add new edits to it too, please

Comment: okay, I'm still now sure what to do with newGame() as you can tell

Comment: Finally! Its working. Thank You! Would you know how to do the user input?

Comment: What do you mean by "user input"?

Comment: I need to have the user put where they want their mark at in the array on the same line. So if they enter.... 3 2....3 will be [i] and 2 will be [j]

Comment: You can do Scanner.nextLine(), and then make split() for input String

Comment: I appreciate all your help! I'm going to try that